# Datasheet view export

Tags: sharepoint-server, sql, datasheet

I am using a datasheet view in sharepoint to manage an excel like sheet that multiple users can modify there data in. right now i export the list manually and upload it to the service provider. I am looking to automate this routine and looking for suggestions and even an example if someone has done it.

In the past I would do a SQL query, however we all know sharepoint is structured a little weird.

My goal is to automate the process end to end and take the middle man out of someone doing the upload piece.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, are you saying you export the Sharepoint list to excel and then upload it to somewhere else outside of Sharepoint?

Depending on why you upload it to somewhere else, why don't you use SQL Server Reporting Services to create a report on the data and have that report saved as a pdf/excel file to a set location at timed intervals?

Alternatively, use an access file linked to the SP list and kept in the location you are uploading to so that the users can edit their details there and you cut out the uploading part altogether (again, this depends on why and where you are uploading the file elsewhere).

Comment: The last option is not going to work because it is an automated system the uploading needs to happen to to give information to the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list using the SharePoint REST API from your favorite programming language.

For example: you could write a Powershell script that downloads the content of the list (record by record) and uploads the result using FTP